# Concrete5: Change link in the header section

Tags: php, concrete5

I have this div content in my header.php file contained in application/themes/custom_name/elements

```
<?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
    $this->inc('elements/header_top.php');
    $cl_txt = $c->getAttribute('client_login_txt');
    $cl_url = $c->getAttribute('client_login_url');
?>
......
<div class="login">
    <a href="<?php echo $cl_url ?>" target="_blank">
        <button type="button" class="btn-login"><?php echo $cl_txt ?></button>
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like to change the link contained in the div.
Where can I do it?

Comment: Change the value of `$c->getAttribute('client_login_url');`. You probably need to edit `$c`.

Comment: It depends on what `$c` is and where it is initialized.

Comment: Yes. That's what the question is about

Comment: This depends on if you need to have a dynamic or static link. Can you explain your use case of the link that you need to stick it in in place of the 'client_login_url'? As for what $c is in concrete5; it is the page enclosed in a variable and I would advise against hacking $c.

Comment: It was a static link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two Page Attributes, the link URL is called Client Link URL and the link text is called Client Link Text, I was able to edit this by going to Full Sitemap and click on the page I am trying to change and select Attributes.